# React Router useHistory. History.push changes url but does not load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I want to have a simple button that when clicked redirects a user to a route defined in my Index.tsx file.

When the button is clicked, the url bar is correctly changed to "/dashboard", however my component (just an h1) does not appear. If I reload chrome at that point it will appear.

Here's my code (Index.tsx):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

const appHistory = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router history={appHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
   document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

Here's my start of a Login form (the first route above, App, renders it).
(Login.tsx):

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";
 import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

 export const Login: React.FC = (props) => {
     const classes = useStyles();
     let history = useHistory();

     const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
     const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

     const validateForm = (): boolean => {
        return true;
     };

     const handleLoginClick = (
       event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
      ) => {
         history.push("/dashboard");
     };

     return (
        <form>
         <div>
           <Button
            onClick={handleLoginClick}
            color="inherit"
            type="button"
           >
            Login
           </Button>
         </div>
        </form>
       );
 };

 export default Login;
```

Comment: [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-k8cpc?file=/src/index.js)
Let me know if you have questions. It seems that using the Router component from 'react-router' does not work. but using the Router from 'react-router-dom' does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line

```
import { Router } from "react-router"
```

with

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just coming back to "answer" my question when I saw yours. That's what it was! Thanks

Comment: This works for me but why am I getting a warning: `To use a custom history, use import { Router } instead of import { BrowserRouter as Router }`

Answer (score 2):

Try importing the `Router` from `react-router-dom` - the rest seems correct

```
import { Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

`react-router` is mostly for internal usage - you only interact with `react-router-dom`